# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to fix this SQL state error from the past 30 mins.
What am I doing wrong here?
Any suggestions are welcome.

```
$statement=$conn->prepare("SELECT to.ipaddress as ipaddress, to.email as email, to.orderdate as orderdate, to.is_completed as is_completed, p.price as price from temporder to, products p WHERE to.productid = p.productid AND to.ipaddress=? AND to.orderdate=? ");
$statement->execute(array(
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
date('Y-m-d')
));
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**Complete error**

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to, products p WHERE to.productid = p.productid AND to.ipaddress='::1' AND to.or' at line 1

Comment: Post full error message

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid - Update


I'm not sure why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TO` (which you are using as an ALIAS) is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL , you need to surround it in backticks.

From a part of your query...

```
e as price from temporder to, products p WHERE to
                         ^^^^ //<----- That's a reserved word. !
```

Wrap them under backtick like below..

```
e as price from temporder `to`, products p WHERE to
```

Comment: Ah! 
Thanks mate.
Sometimes these small things can create large errors.

Answer (score 2):

`to` is a reserved key word

so u need to wrap it within backtics as

```
`to`
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html